# angularjs homepage encountered a declaration exception

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am doing automation testing using protractor with testlink.
https://github.com/Baltino/protractor-testlink
I cloned the following project in my device and changed the necessary IDs.
After execution I am getting "Process exited with error code 1".
Failures:
1)angularjs homepage encountered a declaration exception
Message:
    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

```
  testprojectname: 'Protractor Calculator'
  // testprojectname: 'PTR_CAL_-:Protractor Calculator'
  }, function(project){
  console.log('Test Project:');
  console.log(project);
  });
```

"Process exited with error code 1".
Failures:
1)angularjs homepage encountered a declaration exception
Message:
    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Does the stack trace of the error reference any particular files? Might be worth including the stack trace if you can

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5J7HyYn1ek0/XO0HblqlafI/AAAAAAAACuA/gQwFpKXS9mI2ECNirbi6y6kYXeKu6dOMQCK8BGAs/s0/2019-05-28.png